# Jquery function cant access json object

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using bootstrap validator to validate my form data. If form is validated I'm posting those data to php. In php I'm returning json string. Even though my post is success and get correct response, I can't access json object.

```
$('#dealForm')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        fields: {
            deal_description: {
                message: 'The deal discription is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The deal discription is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var formObj = $(e.target);

        var formURL = formObj.attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            dataType:JSON
        }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    });
```

debugger output

[image]

php

```
$temp= $_POST['deal_description'];
        if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){$temp2='has';} else $temp2='no has';
        echo json_encode(array(
            'message' => $temp,
            'test' => $temp2
        ));
```

Comment: "message" is spelt wrong here: `alert(data.mesage);`

Comment: Not the actual problem. console.log also not giving correct output

Comment: So exactly what do you want to access..?
message OR TEST

Comment: lets say message. but my main problem is can't even access "data"

Answer (score 0):

Either set the correct header in php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
        'message' => $temp,
        'test' => $temp2
    ));
```

**Or** use JSON.parse in js:

```
}).done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    alert(data.mesage);
        });
```

EDIT just noticed you also have a spelling mistake in your js. `data.mesage` should have two s `data.message`

Comment: This did not solved my problem. Results are still the same. Console.log does not giving any output. But thanx for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request is wrong I think. It should be

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        workWithData(data);
    }).done(function(e){
        console.log("I'm done");
    });
}

function workWithData(data){
    if (typeof data != 'undefined') {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

The reason for having it in a second function is that it is a callback. We don't know how long the AJAX request might take, so we must not interrupt execution of the page whilst waiting for a response. By using a callback, when the data eventually arrives it will be processed.

I'd like to recommend you go through this to learn more about AJAX requests http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Is anything appearing in the console at all?

Comment: Check out my edit. You're getting the data back successfully, you're just not doing anything with it as far as I can see.

Comment: Not worked. I think data is not getting successfully.

Comment: Remove `processData:false` or set it to true. What happens when you click the JSON tab on your debugger? Does it show valid JSON?

Comment: after processData:true -> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59502/discussion-between-dushan-and-mightylampshade).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.done(function(data) {
        var res=$.parseJSON(data);
        alert(res.message);       
  });
```